# Shortcut for current class when referring to class variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, self

I have a class variable `BASE_MATCHER` like this (value shared among all instances, if I understod correctly)

```
class PatchsetBase():
    # https://github.com/kullo/smartsqlite
    BASE_MATCHER = re.compile("https://github.com/([-a-z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\.git)?")

    def __init__(self, url):
        match = BASE_MATCHER.match(url)
        if not match:
            raise InvalidGithubUrl("base url is not valid: '" + url + "'")
        self.user = match.group(1)
        self.project = match.group(2)
```

Now Python3 tells me in the constructor:

> NameError: name 'BASE_MATCHER' is not defined

I need to explicitly call `PatchsetBase.BASE_MATCHER` for this to work.

Is there any elegant way to get rid of this redundancy?

Comment: ...`self.BASE_MATCHER`? As you mention, the class attribute is shared among all instances, and can therefore be accessed on them.

Comment: @jonrsharpe probably… only question I have is whether it's intended to be a class or an instance variable.

Comment: @jonrsharpe is there any way a reader can distinguish if this is a class or an instance variable? Can't I differentiate between my instance (`self`) and my class (xyz)?

Comment: Do they need to? The naming convention alone should be a big clue, and it's pretty common to access class attributes via `self`. You could use `self.__class__.BASE_MATCHER`, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: @SimonWarta if you create a class method using the classmethod decorator, you must pass it the class instead of the instance. Thus, you would have access to class properties instead of instance properties. There's also [a classproperty module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/classproperty/1.0). YMMV

Comment: @jonrsharpe They do because they should me aware of side effects when changing the variable. But it looks like naming convention is the key point here

Answer (score 2):

One option is making it visible inside `__init__` by passing a third default argument to it containing the `BASE_MATCHER` object you need to access:

```
def __init__(self, url, matcher=BASE_MATCHER):
    match = matcher.match(url)
    if not match:
        raise InvalidGithubUrl("base url is not valid: '" + url + "'")
    self.user = match.group(1)
    self.project = match.group(2)
```

Now you can access this object inside `__init__` with no `NameError` raised. You could also just name the default arg `BASE_MATCHER`, if that is an issue here:

```
def __init__(self, url, BASE_MATCHER=BASE_MATCHER):
    match = BASE_MATCHER.match(url)
```

This does the trick but I'll be honest, *it does makes me feel a bit uncomfortable*.

The other option (as pointed out in the comments) is using `self` to access the shared object with `self.BASE_MATCHER`. This is the natural way of accessing class variables, but, what I don't know is if this, from a visual aspect at least, seems more elegant than `PatchsetBase.BASE_MATCHER`.

Either way, not exactly sure what you define as elegant, but these are two simple options you could consider.

Comment: Yeah, the first version really adds a lot of noise and cannot be scaled to larger code bases. `self` is fine, when combined with a strong naming convention, as @jonrsharpe mentioned. Otherwise the user of a variable does not know which scope is affected when changing the value.

Comment: @SimonWarta indeed. I can't really think of some other way that would involve cluttering code completely, maybe I'm missing something (using `global` vars would be a naive and really unrecommended way). Give it some time, maybe offer a bounty.